# Issue with php file_get_contents() in xampp running on Mac OS X

Tags: php, macos, file-get-contents

I wrote a PHP script which reads all JSON files in a directory. It processes the contents and creates a different array with required values. The script is called from AJAX with the returned value, and a CSV is created by JavaScript, which is downloaded on the client's computer.

It is working fine on my computer. I'm running Windows 7 on my PC and I have XAMPP installed.

I gave the program to a friend but the program isn't working on his computer. The PHP debug info shows that `file_get_contents()` is returning null on his computer. He has a Mac.

```
$data = array();
$dh = opendir(__DIR__);
while($file = readdir($dh)) {
    if (strpos($file, '.json') !== false) {
        $contents = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/' . $file);
        $contents = json_decode($contents, true);

        if(array_key_exists('exchange', $contents)) {
```

The error is thrown on `if(array_key_exists('exchange', $contents)) {` and shows

> Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null
>   given in...

I cannot understand what the problem might be, as I have not used a Mac. Possible issues I thought might be:

1. The path to the file
2. I am not clear about how `__DIR__` works
3. permissions for `file_get_contents()`

I tried resolving the issue and searched the web a lot but did not get anything specific.

I would like to know what is going wrong and how to resolve the issue and make the program work on the Mac.

Comment: May be your files are not containing valid json data. So your json_decode function is returning null. Please check.

Comment: We are working on the same set of data files. The directory contains 1500 json files that are being read as valid on my computer. But his computer shows the said errors.

Comment: Can you check this for single json file? Or else you check by json_last_error
()

Comment: I have tried with single file. Same results. Runs on mine doesn't run on the other person's.

Comment: @Ghadeer: thanks for wanting to improve posts here. However, your edit on this occasion should not have been accepted in the Review Queue, and had to be repaired by someone else. Technologies like PHP and JavaScript do not need to be rendered in inline code formatting, since they are proper nouns and not code. Please fix the case for these and only use monospace formatting for inline code samples and computer I/O. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the repeated edits. But I would appreciate more if someone helped me solve the issue rather than correcting the grammar in the question.